# Why does struct.pack throw an exception that seems to have no type?

Tags: python, exception

I want to use the correct exception type instead of the generic `except Exception`, however, I'm not sure how to find the proper type. Here is a code snippet to demonstrate the behavior. Passing in a `None` instead of an integer is not allowed as it's trying to pack it into an unsigned long.

```
>>> import struct
>>> try:
...     b = struct.pack("L", None)
... except Exception as ex:
...     print(f"An exception of type {type(ex).__name__} occurred. {ex.args}")
...
An exception of type error occurred. ('required argument is not an integer',)
```

What is the recommended way to catch an exception from pack? Or am I stuck with checking all the arguments to `pack()` to make sure they are valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are catching an exception of type `struct.error` apparently.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html):

> exception struct.error
>
> Exception raised on various occasions; argument is a string describing what is wrong.

If you just do

```
 print(f"{type(ex)}")
```

it prints `<class 'struct.error'>`

---

Also, just to confirm

```
try:
    struct.pack("L", None)
except struct.error as ex:
    print("Caught")
```

prints `Caught`

Comment: Thanks much! Read the doc but somehow missed that at the top. I got it to return "error" as the type, but "except error as ex" doesn't work.

Comment: This strikes me as one of the more unpythonic things in the standard library, both the name (what's wrong with `StructError`?) and the fact that it seems to cover a wide range of different exceptions that might have extended `ValueError`, `TypeError`, etc.

Comment: @e-holder yes, a lot could be said about the naming... I also just found it out now and was kind of perplexed...

Comment: @e-holder `struct.error` is just a regular module attribute reference; you can catch `error` alone if you do something like `from struct import error`, or you can give it a more conventional name with `from struct import error as StructError` and use `except StructError as ex`.